# Software to lock files when open to prevent edit conflicts

Tags: windows, file-management

I'm looking for a third party Windows tool that can automatically create a lock file when it is opened by someone.

I am experimenting with files such as plain text, AutoCAD and Photoshop stored on cloud file storage such as Google Drive and Dropbox, which are synchronised to local disk. So these files can vary from a 1KB up to 300MB.

The scenario is quite simple, two users have the same folder shared.

- If user 1 opens a file within that folder (whether it's for editing or viewing), a lock file is auto-created (which should auto-sync back to the cloud).
- If user 2 attempts to open the same file, the lock file (created by user 1) is found and an alert or notification would appear, ideally to say user 1 has the file open.

It's a basic file locking idea, but any idea to avoid conflicting edits between users would help. I wonder if there is any third party tool out there to achieve this. I understand offline edits are pretty unavoidable.